# ANSI C: Insert elements to array

Tags: arrays, c, ansi-c

What's the easiest way to push elements to an array?

I have the following code for printing files in my directory:

```
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir(".");

if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if (dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
    }
}
closedir(d);
```

This is the output:

```
File1.c
File2.c
File3.c
```

I'd like to add them to an array like this:

```
arr[] = {"File1.c","File2.c","File3.c"};
```

So I can easily call any given item like this **arr[1]** and get **"File2.c"**

How can I accomplish this?

(I learned C a few years ago, but now I don't remember how to do it exactly)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `malloc()` to allocate the space when needed. You create an array of pointers with a maximum number of files you will support. Then you fill in the pointers to memory created by `malloc()` and copy your value to that location.

```
char *arr[NUMBER_OF_FILES];
arr[i] = malloc(strlen(*(dir->d_name)) + 1);
strcpy(arr[i], *(dir->d_name));
```

You can access the elements later with:

```
printf(*(arr[0])) //this will output "File1.c"
```

**Update**:
As suggested by Ferdinand in the comments, you could avoid `malloc()` by using `strdup()`:

```
char *arr[NUMBER_OF_FILES];
arr[i] = strdup(dir->d_name);
```

> **Important**:
>   Remember to use `free()` for all allocated memory to avoid memory leakage.

Comment: You might want to use `strdup()` to duplicate the strings -- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't lend itself to the easy construction of variable size collections.  There are basically two ways to do what you want:

### The easy, sloppy way:

```
DIR *d;
char *list[100000];  // More room than you're likely to need
int count = 0;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir(".");

if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if (dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
            list[count] = strdup(dir->d_name);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
closedir(d);
/* At this point, "count" contains the number of "real" items in your array.
 * Remember to free the memory used by the strings when you're done
 */
```

### The harder, more elegant way

```
DIR *d;
char **list = (char **)malloc(8*sizeof(char *));
int count = 0;
int size = 8;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir(".");

if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if (dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
            if(count > size)            // We've filled up the existing space in the array
            {                           // So make it larger
                size *= 2;              // Doubling each time we run out of room is a good heuristic.
                list = (char **)realloc(size * sizeof(char *));
            }
            list[count] = strdup(dir->d_name);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
closedir(d);
/* At this point, "count" contains the number of "real" items in your array.
 * Remember to free the memory used by the strings and the list when you're done
 */
```

### The really hard, "proper" way

Write an "array" abstract data type, with functions for "push", "pop", "append", etc.  The details are left as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score -1):

Make an array big enough to hold all the directories.
Char* str[1000]
Declare an index
Int qq =0
And them like that
Str[qq++] = name

This will be an array of pointers so it won't take much memory

Comment: You will end up with with invalid pointers.  You have to copy the strings.

Comment: `readdir()` and `closedir()` must not leak memory.  So the space for the file name will be freed -- most likely on every call to `readdir()`, but eventually by `closedir()`.  `readdir()` is even allowed to pass the same pointer on every call for the same directory stream.  In other words: The pointer returned by `readdir()` must not be accessed any more after the next call for the same directory stream.